# Playback of Beatsmusic audio API not working

Tags: rtmp, beatsmusic

I have followed the instructions here to no avail:
  https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/web_playback_api/Getting_Started

Everything loads, but no music plays.

I have also tried their simple example:
  https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/web_playback_api/Examples

But again, no streaming occurred.  In both cases, no errors are thrown, but also no music.

I've tried multiple debug techniques, etc.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the simple example on JSFiddle it makes the bam_engine object 500px x 300px.  Do you see the Black console window when you run your html? Do you see it when you load the simple example page at JSFiddle?  If you can't see it in your local html page, but you can see it on JSFiddle, then you do not have the location of your html file set as a trusted location. Setting a trusted location is explained on the getting started page.

Comment: That's not it.  The directory on my local machine is set per your instructions.  Any other hints?

Comment: Also, are you saying that jsfiddle is working because the black console shows?  Do you have a web-based example that will actually play the musical track?

Comment: The black console is the swf that handles playback. If you adjust the size of your bam_engine element in the browser and do not see it, then that is the issue. If you replace the client_id, access_token, user_id and track in the JSFiddle example with valid values from the developer playground, it will play.

Comment: "If you adjust the size of your bam_engine element in the browser and do not see it, then that is the issue".  What are you referring to when you say 'that is the issue'?  Are you saying I'm using a faulty browser?  I have all the correct data (parameters), I hit 'run' and then the bam_engine console disappears.

Comment: If you replace the client_id, access_token, user_id and track_id in the JS Fiddle simple example, your console disappears and you get no playback?